# Module not found: Can't resolve 'schedule' in 'C:\Users\adcal\dvmtn7\myapp\node_modules\react-dom\cjs'

Tags: reactjs, package.json

```
./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'schedule' in 'C:\Users\adcal\dvmtn7\myapp\node_modules\react-dom\cjs'
```

this same error has happened three create-react-apps in a row. It works at first and then just randomly breaks.

I have only installed modules via npm. Here's the package.json

```
  {
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "massive": "^5.3.0",
    "react": "^16.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5",
    "redux": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Update: I have the "schedules" npm installed in the projects node module folder. Why is it still throwing this error though? 
(It happens in all of my projects now.)

Update to the update: I reinstalled create-react-app globally it fixed it.

Comment: You say you have the "schedules" package installed but it isn't listed in package.json. Are you sure you installed it?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `schedule` got moved out of react in a later version.

Try

```
npm install scheduler --save
```

or updating react

https://www.npmjs.com/package/scheduler

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason for this error is that there was a problem installing or updating a module.

I solved the problem in the following ways.

1. Remove **package-lock.json** and **node_modules** folder.
2. Run the `npm install` command to install a package again.
3. Run the `yarn start` command to confirm that the error has been resolved.